# Next.JS dynamic route navigation shows wrong page

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes

I have the following problem.

In our Next.JS project we have 3 pages:

`/documents` => shows all documents
`/document/[id]/index.js` => shows document page
`/document/[id]/edit.js`=> shows document edit page

Quite simple so far.
On all these page we use an useDocument hook with `router.query.id | props.id (from getServerSideProps)` which loads the document with SWR.

This generally works without problems.
But when i open a document page, then go back to the documents list and then try to open a different document in the edit page it correctly shows the browser url with /edit in the end, but somehow shows the document view page and not the edit page. When i refresh, everything works fine and the edit page is opened.
This only happens in production mode and i cannot recreate it locally which is very annoying. In addition, which is very strange, it does not happen, when i open the react dev tools^^

What i found out so far is that sometimes the `props.id` is still the id of the last document and the `router.query.id` contains the new document. But still the old document is not shown anymore, but the new one on the wrong page. I also try to switch to always load the document with the `router.query.id` but that didn't work either.

What i found is that Next.JS has some issues with not refreshing state when switching dynamic pages, but that didn't helped me so far.

Does anyone experienced something similar?